# React event.stopPropagation() is not stopping the navigation

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and stuck in the following scenario. I want to stop navigation after clicking on this link. Am I doing something wrong ?

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
    handleRemoveClick(event, id) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(event);
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.props.onRemoveClick(event,id);
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <li>{this.props.item.text}
            <a href="#">
              <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
              onClick={()=>this.handleRemoveClick(event,this.props.item.id)}></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing in the event like this.

```
<li>{this.props.item.text}
        <a href="#">
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
          onClick={(event)=>this.handleRemoveClick(event,this.props.item.id)}></span>
        </a>
</li>
```

Comment: After doing the mentioned changes, `event.preventDefault()` is working fine.  `event.stopPropagation()` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recomend using arrow functions inside of render in React. Reasons are explained here: [Why arrow functions and bind in React's render are problematic](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36)

With that explained, your solution should be in the lines of:

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
    handleRemoveClick = id => event => {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onRemoveClick(event,id);
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <li>{this.props.item.text}
            <a href="#">
              <span 
                className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
                onClick={this.handleRemoveClick(this.props.item.id)} 
              />
            </a>
        </li>
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the right way, you're directly calling the function in render, it will be called even without real click on the button.